# Stop previous random activity from showing

Tags: java, android, random

Does anyone know how to completely stop the random activity from showing? I have 5 classes with 10 questions each. Once the correct answer is given I want to move on to the next random class and not have the previous class come up again. Once all the random classes are answered the first time, then the Random method has ended. I tried finish() but that doesn't work. On button click I still get repeated classes after it has already been answered. Please see my code and advise if you could. Thx

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView myTv;
Button nextBtn;
EditText myEt;
Button playgameBtn;

int mCounter = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    myTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTv);
    nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
    playgameBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playgameBtn);
    myEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEt);


   final String[] clazzes = new String[] {"Mark.class", "John.class", "Caleb.class", "Isaiah.class", "Jacob.class"};


    playgameBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ArrayList<Class> activityList = new ArrayList<>();
            activityList.add(Mark.class);
            activityList.add(John.class);
            activityList.add(Caleb.class);
            activityList.add(Isaiah.class);
            activityList.add(Jacob.class);


            Random generator = new Random();
            int number = generator.nextInt(5)*1;

            Class activity = null;

            switch (number){
                case 1:
                    activity = John.class;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    activity = Caleb.class;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    activity = Mark.class;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    activity = Isaiah.class;
                    break;
                default:
                    activity = Jacob.class;
                    break;


            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activity);



             startActivity(intent);
            finish();

            }

private void finish() {
}


    });


      }



  }
```

Comment: Have you considered using fragments and saving the questionnaire process?

Comment: No, not to sure on how to handle fragments.

Answer (score 0):

This is not good approach of programming. Solution for you can be : Remove that empty finish function from the code.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView myTv;
Button nextBtn;
EditText myEt;
Button playgameBtn;

int mCounter = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

myTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTv);
nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
playgameBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playgameBtn);
myEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEt);


final String[] clazzes = new String[] {"Mark.class", "John.class", "Caleb.class", "Isaiah.class", "Jacob.class"};
playgameBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ArrayList<Class> activityList = new ArrayList<>();
        activityList.add(Mark.class);
        activityList.add(John.class);
        activityList.add(Caleb.class);
        activityList.add(Isaiah.class);
        activityList.add(Jacob.class);


        Random generator = new Random();
        int number = generator.nextInt(5)*1;

        Class activity = null;

        switch (number){
            case 1:
                activity = John.class;
                break;
            case 2:
                activity = Caleb.class;
                break;
            case 3:
                activity = Mark.class;
                break;
            case 4:
                activity = Isaiah.class;
                break;
            default:
                activity = Jacob.class;
                break;


        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activity);



         startActivity(intent);
        finish();

        }

});


  }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using `Collections.shuffle()` instead to randomize the items and then 'popping' the last item of the list after calling the activity.

```
        ArrayList<Class> activityList = new ArrayList<>();
        activityList.add(Mark.class);
        activityList.add(John.class);
        activityList.add(Caleb.class);
        activityList.add(Isaiah.class);
        activityList.add(Jacob.class);
        Collections.shuffle(activityList);

     playgameBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


       Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activityList.get(0));
        startActivity(intent);
        activityList.remove(0);

        }

        [...]
```

Keep in mind that you should add the objects to the ArrayList outside the `setOnClickListener` method

Comment: I forgot to mention, Don't call finish(). And remove the empty finish function as well, like the other user suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use fragments which is the recommended way of normally doing this sort of thing, I would give you a very basic example addition to what you've already provided.

```
//make a list as an instance variable
private static List<Integer> displayedClasses;

//In your onClick event get the random number as follows
int number=getRandomNumber();
//getRandomNumber() will return -1 if all classes are displayed. Handle it here.
if(number==-1){
   displayedClasses.clear();
   //do something else
   return;
}
//store the number in the above list
if(displayedClasses==null)displayedClasses=new ArrayList<>();
displayedClasses.add(new Integer(number));

//continue with the rest of the statement
```

getRandomNumberMethod

```
private int getRandomNumber(){
    if(l.size()>=5) {
       return -1;
    }
    Random random=new Random();
    int num=0;
    while(l.contains(num)){
        num=random.nextInt(5)*1;
    }
    return num;
}
```